# tikz ploting parabola using math

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hi I am trying to plot the parabola `4-x^2` over the interval `-2;2` using `tikz`.

If I use this code I don't get the desired plot:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2, scale = 0.75]
\draw[black, line width = 0.50mm]   plot[smooth,domain=-2:2] (\x, {4-\x^2});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If I use this code, I get the desired plot.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2, scale = 0.75]
\draw[black, line width = 0.50mm]   plot[smooth,domain=0:2] (\x, {4-\x^2});
\draw[black, line width = 0.50mm]   plot[smooth,domain=-2:0] (\x, {4+\x^2});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My question: Can anyone explain me why the first one doesn't work but the second one work?

thanks

Comment: Try `\x*\x`, btw much easier with pgfplots then `\addplot[no marks] {4-x^2};` works fine, no fuzz

Comment: ty, `\x*\x` woked! i'll try to read about pgfplots! 
So \x^2 is not doing the correct calculation. but then if I want to plot `x^6`, it is kind of not fun to type `\x*\x*\x*\x*\x*\x`. So my new question is:  Is there a way to use something like `exp(\x;6)` type of function?

Comment: I'll add it as an answer. You'll love `pgfplots` it is very very powerfull and flexible.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that tikz alone does not process `\x^2` as `(\x)^2` so a sign gets lost. A quick fix could be to use `\x*\x` which seems to work, as does `(\x)^2`

Even easier though is to use `pgfplots`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
% bad
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2, scale = 0.75]
\draw[black, line width = 0.50mm]   plot[smooth,domain=-2:2] (\x, {4-\x^2});
\end{tikzpicture}

% works
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2, scale = 0.75]
\draw[black, line width = 0.50mm]   plot[smooth,domain=-2:2] (\x, {4-\x*\x});
\end{tikzpicture}

% works
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:2, scale = 0.75]
  \draw[black, line width = 0.50mm]   plot[smooth,domain=-2:2] (\x, {4-(\x)^2});
\end{tikzpicture}

% even more fun
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    domain=-2:2,
    ]
    \addplot[no marks] {4-x^2};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```