# Difficulty with tikz plot command

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wrote this;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\draw[->,line width=1pt] (-2,0)--(2,0) node[right]{$y$}; 
\draw[->,line width=1pt] (0,-2)--(0,2) node[above]{$f(y)$};
\draw[blue,line width=1pt,domain=-2:2, samples=100] plot(\x,\x^2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center} 
 
\end{document}
```

But I got this image:

[image]

What have I done wrong? Please use tikz, not pgfplots and others.

Thanks,

David

Comment: Not an answer, but `plot(\x,{abs(\x^2)})` would get you the desired output, I assume.

Comment: You did nothing wrong, really. Apart from the above, you can also use `plot(\x,{\x*\x})` or `plot(\x,{(\x)^2})`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323312/47927 .

Comment: Your question is dupolicate to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664859/plot-y-x2-with-tikz-plot-command/664863#664863, which has two answers, hoot to solve your problem ...

Comment: Thanks, plot(\x,{(\x)^2}) worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    \draw[->,line width=1pt] (-2,0)--(2,0) node[right]{$y$}; 
    \draw[->,line width=1pt] (0,-2)--(0,2) node[above]{$f(y)$};
    % \draw[blue,line width=1pt,domain=-2:2, samples=100] plot(\x,\x^2);
    \draw[blue,line width=1pt,domain=-2:2, samples=100] plot(\x,{(\x)^2});
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that is suggested in my comment!